# material ui datagrid checkbox row selection is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
 <DataGrid
                className="list"
                pagingation
                rows={registeredClasses} 
                columns={this.getColumns()}
                pageSize={10}
                rowLength={10}
                autoHeight
                // sortModel={sortModel}
                components={{
                  pagination:CustomPagination
                }}
                checkboxSelection
                onSelectionChange={(newSelection) =>{
                  console.log(newSelection)
                }}
                
               
              />
```

tried with onSelectionModelChange as well, selection is happening only if i click on row, if i click on checkbox it is not happening

Comment: The below answer of @jharris711 should work.

Answer (score 8):

## "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.2.1"

`onSelectionModelChange` is now `onRowSelectionModelChange`. From the DataGrid API Docs:

Callback fired when the selection state of one or multiple rows changes.

#### Signature

```js
function(
    rowSelectionModel: GridRowSelectionModel, 
    details: GridCallbackDetails 
) => void
```

For more info, check out the [DOCS HERE](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/)

## v4.0.0-alpha.34 +

Breaking changes were included with Version `v4.0.0-alpha.34`. `onRowSelected` has been removed and `onSelectionModelChange` now returns an array with indexes of the selected rows. You can alter the selection model directly via `onSelectionModelChange`:

#### Example from Material UI Docs:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid'
import { useDemoData } from '@material-ui/x-grid-data-generator'

export default function ControlledSelectionGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: 'Commodity',
    rowLength: 10,
    maxColumns: 6,
  })

  const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = React.useState([])

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        checkboxSelection
        onSelectionModelChange={(newSelectionModel) => {
          setSelectionModel(newSelectionModel)
        }}
        selectionModel={selectionModel}
        {...data}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

[Updated Demo on Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-mccarthy-fch8u?file=/src/App.js)

[Material UI Docs - Controlled Selection](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/selection/#controlled-selection)

[Material UI DataTable Change Log on GitHub](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/releases/tag/v4.0.0-alpha.34)

## Version 4.0.0-alpha.21:

Instead of

```js
onSelectionChange={(newSelection) => {
    console.log(newSelection)
}}
```

Try [onRowSelected](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/), like so:

```js
onRowSelected={(GridRowSelectedParams) => {
    console.log(GridRowSelectedParams);
}}
```

If you want to keep track of the selection state of all rows, you should use this:

```js
onSelectionModelChange={(GridSelectionModelChangeParams) => {
    // This will return {selections: [selected row indexes]}
    console.log(GridSelectionModelChangeParams);
    if (Array.isArray(GridSelectionModelChangeParams.selectionModel)) {
        // Iterate the selection indexes:
        GridSelectionModelChangeParams.selectionModel.forEach(
            // Get the row data:
            (selection_index) => console.log(rows[selection_index])
        );
    }
}}
```

I set up a [Code Sandbox with a working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-greider-m1b26?file=/src/App.js) for you to try out

Comment: Thanks a ton. Everywhere I was seeing onSelectionChange which wasn't working for me but onRowSelected is giving the correct console log now.

Comment: I've tried this with console.logs with me locally and this doesn't work any more. `onRowSelected` doesn't log anything and `onSelectionModelChange` throws this error: `react-dom.development.js?61bb:4091 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.onSelectionModelChange [as propOnChange]`. This was working last week. Any idea about what changed?

Comment: @maestro777 Breaking changes were introduced with version v4.0.0-alpha.34. `onRowSelected` has been removed and `onSelectionModelChanged` has been modified. I've updated the answer with examples from the Docs, the changelog, and added a new demo. I hope it helps!

Comment: @jharris711 It helped me out a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't working for me until I realised `onSelectionModelChange` is now `onRowSelectionModelChange` in MUI DataGrid (using "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.2.1")

For someone like me who has a hard time deciphering docs before coming to stackoverflow I had to figure this out the hard way i.e. by reading docs